# What are the characteristics of cloud-native workloads?

Tags: cloud, cpu, cpu-architecture, intel, cloud-native

Nowadays, many chips adopt designs with lower single core performance but more cores, piecing together a CPU with many cores and high overall computing power, and calling it a cloud native product [[1]](https://www.servethehome.com/cloud-native-efficient-computing-is-the-way-in-2024-and-beyond-supermicro-intel-amd-ampere-nvidia/).

**What are the characteristics of the cloud native load they are targeting that drive such a design? Why can they benefit from more cores and higher overall performance (although only weaker memory bandwidth compared to the growth rate of computing power)**

I searched online for discussions about cloud native, but more focused on program development and deployment, and did not find any discussion on the characteristics of workloads themselves.

Comment: A lot of websites run their back-ends on cloud servers.  Often that includes database workloads, and interpreting languages like Python and PHP.  Usually not HPC.

Comment: @PeterCordes Sorry, I don't quite understand how these workloads are related to the multi-core trend in the development of cloud native CPUs? Or is it that the so-called cloud native CPU is just a commercial promotion?

Comment: Waiting for MESI ownership of a shared cache line doesn't get any faster in a bigger core.  Also, overall throughput matters more than per-core throughput for many scaleable applications like web serving, so 4x as many cores that are each 50% to 90% the speed of a big core is a win, no need to push so far into the diminishing returns of cache size. Also no need to have big wide SIMD execution units if running code that doesn't take any advantage (e.g. CPython without NumPy), hence Intel E-cores.